# Why does my C program keep giving me 1 as the error?

Tags: c, debugging, math

I ran it, and everything seems to be fine--except that it keeps giving me a margin of error of 1. Why is it doing this?

The program is supposed to prompt the user to input an estimation for the cube root of 3, and it uses Newton's method of approximation to show how many attempts it took to get to the approximation. After 500 attempts or a margin of error less than 0.000001, it's supposed to exit the loop. Why, though, doesn't the margin of error change?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float a, i, e;                       //declare float variables
    printf("Consider the function f(x) = x^3 - 3 = 0.\n");
    printf("Simplifying, we get x^3 = 3.\n");
    printf("Simplifying it further, we get x = 3^(1/3).\n");
    printf("Enter your estimate of the root: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);                    //prompt user to guestimate
    printf("So you're saying that x = %f.\n", a);
    i=0;                                //initiate attempt counter
    e=abs((a-pow(3, (1/3)))/pow(3, (1/3)));  //margin of error formula
    while (e>=0.000001 && i<=500)     //initiate while loop with above expressions
    {
        if (a!=pow(3, (1/3)))
        {
            printf("Attempt %f: ", i);
            a = a - (pow(a, 3) - 3)/(3*pow(a, 2));
            printf("%f, ", a);
            printf("%f margin of error\n", e);
            i=i+1;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `(1/3)` in C?

Comment: `e` is set before you enter the loop and never updated

Comment: `1 / 3` is 0. hence, `pow(3, 1/3)` is always 1. Better learn language basics before trying to write nontrivial programs.

Comment: You don't need to call `pow(3, 1.0 / 3.0)` (assuming you correct your mistake) every time the loop is executed.  Just compute it once, store it in a variable, and use that variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abs()` deals with `int`s and will return an `int`, you need `fabsf()`.

In the same way, `pow()` is for `double`s, you should use `powf()`.

Another mistake is writing `1/3` and expecting 0.333... as a result. `1` and `3` are  `int` literals, so the operation performed is integer division. You need to use `float` literals, such as `1.0f/3.0f`.

That's it for type compatibility. I can see another error however : you expect `e` to somehow remember its formula and reapply it automagically. That's not how imperative languages work : when you write `e = something`, "something" is calculated and stored in `e` once and for all. You're doing it correctly for `a`, now just bring `e=abs(...);` inside the `while` loop to update it each time.